# How do I calculate letter frequency percentage?

Tags: java

Having some trouble (lack of understanding) with how to calculate percentages. I need to find out:

> Q1. How do I get the percentage for each letter frequency (out of 100)?, also 
>   Q2. How do I get the letter Frequency for each first word from a paragraph?

Here's my code so far:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class LetterFrequency
{

  public static void main(String[] args )
  {
    char[] capital = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J','K', 'L', 'M', 'N',
                       'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};

    char[] small = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
                     'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };

    Scanner scan;
    try {
      scan = new Scanner(new File("F:/programming principles/Programming Principles - PART B/enciphered.txt"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("File not found");
      return;
    }
    int[] count = new int[26];
    while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
      String line = scan.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Line read: " + line);
      char[] digit = line.toCharArray();
      for(int i = 0; i < digit.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
          if(digit[i] == capital[j] || digit[i] == small[j]) {
            count[j]++;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Comlete count");
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
      System.out.print(" " + small[i]);
      System.out.println(" " + count[i]);
      //calculate percentage for the full count
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: how to want to calculate percentage? suppose if 'a' is there 10 times then what is the percentage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose this is the input you have

```
a A b c d a A B C a
```

and you want to find the percentage then output will be as below

```
a = 50% (as it is 5 time out of 10 alphabet)
b = 20% (as it is 2 time out of 10 alphabet)
c = 20% (as it is 2 time out of 10 alphabet)
d = 10% (as it is 1 time out of 10 alphabet)
```

and total is 10 alphabets.

below are the changes that you will need to do

```
int myTotal = 0;
while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
  String line = scan.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Line read: " + line);
  char[] digit = line.toCharArray();
  for(int i = 0; i < digit.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
      if(digit[i] == capital[j] || digit[i] == small[j]) {
        count[j]++;
        myTotal = myTotal + 1;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Comlete count");
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
  System.out.print(" " + small[i]);
  System.out.print(" " + count[i]);
  if (count[i] > 0)
    System.out.println(" " + (((float) count[i]/myTotal)*100) + "%");
  else
    System.out.println(" 0%");
  //calculate percentage for the full count
}
```

Changes I did in your code are

1. Added variable as

   int myTotal = 0;
2. Added the same variable for counting total alphabets.

   myTotal = myTotal + 1;
3. Removed ln from below line

   System.out.println(" " + count[i]);
4. Added few lines as

   if (count[i] > 0)
       System.out.println(" " + ((count[i]/myTotal)*100) + "%");
     else
       System.out.println(" 0%");

***Please let me know if you have any queries***

### Update 1

I have changed

```
    System.out.println(" " + ((count[i]/myTotal)*100) + "%");
```

to

```
    System.out.println(" " + (((float) count[i]/myTotal)*100) + "%");
```

Comment: to get the same (frequency + percentage for the first letter of each word in the file, is it hasNext, instead of hasNextLine? I struggle to understand this concept...

Comment: to get first letter of each word you will need to use Tokenizer. using  tokenizer find spaces and break one line into arrays and find first letter by myString.charAt(0). Hope you get the hint you wanted..

Answer (score 1):

To work out the percentage, you need to keep track of the `total` number of characters that you have scanned, as well as the counts for each individual character. Every time you read a line, add the number of characters in that line to the total count.

Then at the end, when you're printing out your counts, you need to simply divide the count by the total number of characters scanned (which will give you a number between 0 - 1), and then multiply this by 100 to get the percentage for this character.

```
( count[ i ] / total ) * 100
```

Comment: ...Pretty much exactly what @ThierryT has just posted!

Answer (score 0):

When you count each letter, just increment a global counter (total) then divid number of each letter by total * 100.

From your code, I added //New :

```
int total = 0;   // New
for(int i = 0; i < digit.length; i++) {
for(int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
if(digit[i] == capital[j] || digit[i] == small[j]) {
count[j]++;
total++;   // New
break;
}
}
}
}
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Complete count");
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
System.out.print(" " + small[i]);
System.out.println(" " + count[i]);
//calculate percentage for the full count
if (total > 0)      // New
  System.out.println(" " + ((count[i]/total) * 100) + "%");   // New
}
```

Comment: Thankyou @ThierryT , however It states "cannot find symbol - variable total). ?

Comment: Yes move the line int total; just after the line Scanner scan; to make it visible in the whole main.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        calc();
    }

    public static void calc() {
        int i, j, k;
        String str;
        char c, ch;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a String : ");
        str = scan.nextLine();

        i = str.length();
        for (c = 'A'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
            k = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                ch = str.charAt(j);
                if (ch == c) {
                    k++;
                }
            }
            if (k > 0) {
                float e1 = k;
                float e2 = i;
                double r = (e1 / e2) * 100;

                System.out.println("The character " + c + " has occurred for " + k + " times and its percentage is  " + r + "%");
            }
        }
    }
}
```